# Get request parameter in embedding controller

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony1 i can:

```
blog:
  url:   /blog/slug
  param: { module: blog, action: index }
```

and in action/controller i can get slug with: $request->getParameter('slug');

In Symfony2:

```
blog:
    path:      /blog/{slug}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show }
```

and i create "components" same as Symfony1 - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#templating-embedding-controller

How can i get slug in embedding controller? I tried:

```
$request->query->get('foo');
$request->request->get('bar');
```

but this still return null. In AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show controller working ok.

Comment: show your code, what you embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The param converter will populate the argument with the string from the route.  So here is what your method looks like.

```
class BlogController extends Controller {
    public function showAction($slug) {
        // $slug will contain the value of the string from the route
    }
}
```

So if you wanted to embed this into a twig template it would look like this:

```
{{ render( controller('AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show', {'slug': 'this-is-the-slug' })) }}
```

or from another controller

```
$this->render('AcmeBlogBundle:Blog:show.html.twig', array('slug' => 'this-is-the-slug'));
```

Comment: but i want get slug in embedding controller, not in BlogController

Comment: It works the exact same for embedded controllers, your route definition and your method stay exactly the same, the only difference is that you're generating the request to THIS controller from either another controller or from a twig template.